# Cannot get arrow keys to move cursor in curses (C)

Tags: c, ncurses, curses, keypad

Below is my code. I have a main window with two choices that I want the user to be able to key back and forth to just using KEY_LEFT and KEY_RIGHT. I have it set up in a simple manner right now (or so I thought) by just moving the cursor directly to one of the choices.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int j = 0, highlight = 0, choice;
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();

    WINDOW * mainwin = newwin(20, 52, 0, 0);
    refresh();

    while (1)
    {
        keypad(mainwin, TRUE);
        box(mainwin, 0, 0);
        mvwprintw(mainwin, 1, 1, "             L I C E N S E    P L A T E");
        mvwprintw(mainwin, 3, 2, "RAW ADDITION                          COMPARISON");
        wmove(mainwin, 3, 2);
        wattron(mainwin, A_BLINK);
        refresh();
        wrefresh(mainwin);

        choice = wgetch(mainwin);

       switch(choice)
       {
            case KEY_LEFT:
                wmove(mainwin, 3, 2);
                wrefresh(mainwin);

            case KEY_RIGHT:
                wmove(mainwin, 3, 26);
                wrefresh(mainwin);

            default:
                wmove(mainwin, 3, 2);
                wattroff(mainwin, A_BLINK);
                wrefresh(mainwin);

        }

        if (choice == '\n')
        {
            if (highlight == 0) // RAW ADDITION
            {
                char lp[8];
                char num[10];
                int n;
                WINDOW * win = subwin(mainwin, 30, 45, 1, 1);
                refresh();

                box(win, 1, 1);
                mvwprintw(win, 2, 2, "RAW ADDITION");
                mvwprintw(win, 3, 2, "Enter a license plate and an integer.");
                mvwprintw(win, 5, 3, "._________.          ._____________.");
                mvwprintw(win, 6, 3, "|         |          |             |");
                mvwprintw(win, 7, 3, "'---------'          '-------------'");

                wmove(win, 6, 5);
                wrefresh(win);

                mvwgetnstr(win, 6, 5, lp, 7);
                wrefresh(win);

                wmove(win, 6, 26);
                wrefresh(win);

                mvwgetnstr(win, 6, 26, num, 10);
                wrefresh(win);

                n = atoi(num);
            }
            else // COMPARISON
            {

            }
        }

        if (toupper(choice) == 'Q')
            break;
        else if (choice == KEY_LEFT)
        {
            wmove(mainwin, 3, 2);
            wrefresh(mainwin);
        }
        else if (choice == KEY_RIGHT)
        {
            wmove(mainwin, 3, 26);
            wrefresh(mainwin);
        }
    }

    endwin();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, I have to blocks of code that try to catch when the user presses either the left or right arrow key, and move the cursor in the window to the appropriate selection (RAW ADDRESS or COMPARISON). However, for some reason, I can't get anything to respond to the arrow keys. Is there something I'm missing with either the wmove() function or the keypad() function? What am I not understanding here? Does the move function move relative to where the cursor was last?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `wmove` calls in the switch statement aren't having much effect because the logic leading up to the `wgetch` moves the cursor back to the same point:

```
    wmove(mainwin, 3, 2);
    wattron(mainwin, A_BLINK);
    refresh();
    wrefresh(mainwin);

    choice = wgetch(mainwin);
```

By the way, the `refresh()` calls do not appear needed, in a quick read of the source...